# How to add name in bib file in latex

Tags: latex, bibtex, bibliography, biblatex

I have a name like Catherine de Palo Drid . I want its reference like 
Drid C de P

I add like that

```
    author={Drid, Catherine, de, Palo}
```

I have changed many times the arrangement, but neither works.
Can anyone help? 
THANKS

Answer (score 0):

From the BibTeX documentation (btxdoc.pdf, p. 15/16):

> Each name consists of four parts: First, von, Last, and Jr;
>
> BibTeX allows three possible forms for the name:
>
> ```
> "First von Last"
> "von Last, First"
> "von Last, Jr, First"
> ```

You want to treat "Catherine de Palo" as First and "Drid" as Last, since abbreviating names is only done in First. In that case I would use

```
author = {Drid, Catherine {de} Palo}
```

where the braces around "de" tell BibTeX to not alter that token.